# vue/laravel images not showing (not found) using laravel storage folder

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

am trying to display my images dynamically from laravel storage folder but it says images not found even though i can see the pictures adding up in the folder, i also tried php artisan link but nothing good

```
<v-btn flat v-on="on">
        <div>
          {{connectedUser.name }} {{ connectedUser.last_name }}
          <v-avatar size="38px"">
            <img :src="'http://api.sirh.test/storage/'+connectedUser.img" />
          </v-avatar>
        </div>
      </v-btn>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like `connectedUser.img` is `undefined`

Comment: @keyboardSmasher when i show connectedUser.img its not empty , it returns the img

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
:src=‘getImage(connectedUser)’

getImage(connectedUser){
return /storage/ + connectedUser.img

}